# python3 getting delta of a strptime

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to subtract a formatted strptime datetime, from the current time. In order to subtract a formatted time you have to convert the formatted datetime back into a regular datetime object so it is not a string anymore. However when this is executed the import modules seem to be out of place. If you do a from datetime import * then the it says the module does not have a datetime, and if you do datetime.datetime then the module says it does not have strptime.

```
>>> from datetime import *
>>> (datetime.datetime.now().astimezone(pytz.utc) - datetime.strptime(db_job_document['time_down'], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")).total_seconds()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'
>>> import datetime
>>> (datetime.datetime.now().astimezone(pytz.utc) - datetime.strptime(db_job_document['time_down'], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")).total_seconds()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'
```

Comment: instead of `from datetime import *` use `import datetime`

Comment: Do `import datetime` instead of `from datetime import *` if you want to access the module as `datetime.something...`

Answer (score 0):

There is a need for consistency. If you `import datetime`, remember to access the `datetime` object *within* the `datetime` module.

#### Option 1

```
from datetime import *
# from datetime import datetime, also works in this case

print(datetime.now(), datetime.strptime('2018-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d'), sep='\n')

# 2018-06-25 16:38:39.775445
# 2018-01-01 00:00:00
```

#### Option 2

```
import datetime

print(datetime.datetime.now(), datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d'), sep='\n')

# 2018-06-25 16:39:15.119183
# 2018-01-01 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

`now` and `strptime` are both class methods of the `datetime` object in the `datetime` module. You either import the module `datetime` and then use it as `datetime.datetime` (`.datetime` object of `datetime` module), or you import the `datetime` object itself directly and then just use it as `datetime`:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(...)
>>> datetime.datetime.now()

>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> from datetime import *  # for all intents and purposes the same
>>> datetime.strptime(...)
>>> datetime.now()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import datetime class from datetime module. And for that you need to write - `from datetime import datetime`. Now you can use `datetime.strptime()`.